# sorting a pandas Series not working correctly

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, series

I am trying to sort a given series in python pandas but as per my knowledge it is not correct , it should be like [1,3,5,10,python]

can you please guide on what basis it is sorting this way ?

```
s1 = pd.Series(['1','3','python','10','5'])

s1.sort_values(ascending=True)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tI1Bh.png)

Comment: because it sorts on a string basis

Comment: `'5'>'10'` -> `True`

Comment: try `s1 = pd.Series(['1','3','python','1a','5'])`, that may make the string sorting more obvious.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in the comments, you have strings so `'5'` is greater than `'10'` (strings are compared character by character and `'5' > '1'`).

One workaround is to use [`natsort`](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) for natural sorting:

```
from natsort import natsort_key

s1.sort_values(ascending=True, key=natsort_key)
```

output:

```
0         1
1         3
4         5
3        10
2    python
dtype: object
```

alternative without `natsort` (numbers first, strings after):

```
key = lambda s: (pd.concat([pd.to_numeric(s, errors='coerce')
                              .fillna(float('inf')), s], axis=1)
                   .agg(tuple, axis=1)
                 )
s1.sort_values(ascending=True, key=key)
```